# Passing data from View to Controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a View that gets some bits of data via Action methods that return JSON data.
Depending on the combination of selected options, the user can fill some fields in a page.
What is the best way to pass the data back to a controller, in order to be saved?

- The fields that contain data vary on the options selected;
- I don't have a ViewModel object with all fields bound to the View.

At the moment I have this:

```
@Ajax.BeginForm("MyAction", null, new AjaxOptions
            {
            }, new { @id = "SaveForm" } )
{
    .....
    @Html.RadioButton("SomeRadioButton", "bla", false, new { @id = "SomeRadioButton" })
    .....
    @Html.TextArea("SomeTextArea", new { @id = "SomeTextArea" })
    .....
    <a href="#" onclick="$('#SaveForm').submit();">Save</a>
}
```

How do I get all of those control values in the Action?

I can add something like:

```
public void MyAction(FormCollection form)
{
    .........
}
```

But I don't really like this option.
What's the cleanest way to implement this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string SomeRadioButton { get; set; }
    public string SomeTextArea { get; set; }

    ... 
}
```

and then have your controller action take this view model as argument and leave the default model binder do its job:

```
[HttpPost]
public void MyAction(MyViewModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

I would also take advantage of this view model in the view in order to use strongly typed versions of the helpers:

```
@Ajax.BeginForm("MyAction", null, new AjaxOptions { }, new { @id = "SaveForm" })
{
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.SomeRadioButton)
    ...
    @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.SomeTextArea)
    ...
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
}
```

Comment: I was trying to do this without the model binder, but I see the way to collect all data from the View has to go through the binder. Experimenting a bit here ;)

Comment: @Dante, no, not necessary. You could use FormCollection if you want (you probably don't want). In the controller action in order to fetch the value you use `form["SomeTextArea"]`. Of course this will return the value as string. It's up to you to then parse it to the underlying data type, perform the validation manually, ... things that are already handled for you by the default model binder.

Comment: So, validation and data types are the main reason to choose one over the other. Thank you Darin!

Comment: @Dante, and strongly typing and compile time safety.

Answer (score 1):

You can (and mostly should) use custom class for this, which will hold all fields. Read further about [Model Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410405.aspx) - that's the way to do it with MVC.